# vba criando abas que ultrapassam 31 caracteres - erro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

os dados ultrapassam os limites de caracteres para nomear abas no excel.

Como poderia resolver isso?

```
Sub compilação()

linha = 1
linha_fim = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Range("B2:B" & linha_fim).Copy
Range("U1").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$U$1:$U$" & linha_fim).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
    xlNo

linha_fim = Range("U1").End(xlDown).Row

While linha <= linha_fim
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Base").Cells(linha, 2)

    **Tamanho = Len(ActiveSheet.Name)
    If Tamanho > 30 Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = Mid(ActiveSheet.Name, Tamanho - 30, 30)
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet**

    Sheets("Base").Range("A1:S1").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    linha = linha + 1
Wend

Sheets("Base").Range("U:U").Clear

linha = 2

While Sheets("Base").Cells(linha, 1) <> ""
    Sheets("Base").Range("A" & linha & ":S" & linha).Copy

    Naturezas = Sheets("Base").Cells(linha, 2)
    Sheets(Naturezas).Select
    Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets("Base").Select

    linha = linha + 1
Wend

For Each aba In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    aba.Columns("A:S").AutoFit
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Esta é uma limitação do Excel, uma das inúmeras não documentadas, não há código para mudar isso. Existem algumas formas de contornar o problema, como abreviar palavras, etc... Ou limitar a quantidade de caracteres para 31 e não escrever além disso no nome da aba.

Comment: é que a BD já bem com o nome que preciso para nomear as abas, e esses nomes muitas vezes ultrapassam o limite de caracteres. Teria como "editar" essa base de uma vez só limitando o número de caracteres na célula para até 31. Acho que daí até poderia funcionar

Answer (score -1):

Eu acredito que excel só permite nomes com até 30 caracteres para nome de abas.

Eu não sei o que tem nessas células mas você poderia usar uma das funções de substring: LEFT, MID, RIGHT. Elas podem pegar parte da sua string. Left contando do começo, mid de um local especificado e right a partir da direta.

Mid(texto, número_caractere_inicial, quantidade_caracteres)

```
NomePlanilhaAtual = Sheets("relatorio_despacho-1").Cells(linha, 21)
Tamanho = Len(NomePlanilhaAtual)
IF Tamanho > 30 Then
   NomePlanilhaAtual = Mid(NomePlanilhaAtual, Tamanho - 30, 30)
End If
ActiveSheet.Name = NomePlanilhaAtual
```

Comment: Valeu pela atenção aí brother, vou copiar o código aqui não deu certo.